# call function periodically in javascript until finished, then start calling different function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two functions on my page that I need to call periodically, but in a certain way only.

function_a needs to be run periodically when the page loads, until data is available and downloaded.

After this point, function_b then needs to run periodically forever.

I can easily do...

```
setInterval(function_a, 1000);
setInterval(function_b, 5000);
```

But this will run both functions from the start of page load and forever.

How can I stop function_a running once I have determined that it is not needed anymore, and only start function_b running after this point?

I can put checks within the function_a and function_b code so that they dont execute if not needed, but it seems very wasteful to still call them continually when they are not needed.

```
function_a(){
 if (needed) { code here... }
}

function_b(){
 if (needed) { code here... }
}
```

There must be a better way than that?

Comment: how about using `clearInterval()` when you are done with function_a?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a `setInterval` here, `setTimeout` will work far better.

```
function a() {
  //do stuff

  if(condition) setTimeout(b, 5000)
  else setTimeout(a, 1000)
}

function b(){
  //do stuff

  setTimeout(b, 5000)
}

a()
```

This way, the function will execute and schedule itself to run again on the desired interval. This is similar to the way `requestAnimationFrame` is used for creating animations.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign a variable to `setInterval()` call  and use `clearInterval()`

```
let a = setInterval(function_a, 1000);

function_b() {
  if (a_is_not_needed) { clearInterval(a) }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `clearInterval()` to stop a function called in a `setInterval()`

```
var needed = false;

var f1 = function(){ 
    console.log("Fct1"); 
    if(needed){
        setInterval(f2, 5000); // start f2 when f1 is finish
        clearInterval(interval); // stop to call periodically f1
    }
}   
var f2 = function(){ 
    console.log("Fct2"); 
}

var interval = setInterval(f1, 1000);
```

Try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u26on52m/) and open console to see the result